# Legend in multiple plots Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, legend, figure

How can I put the legend on each graph separately like (figure 2)  instead of putting the legend on the side like (figure 1) ?

Figure 1

[image]

Figure 2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest thing would be to use the `text(x,y,textstring)` function to put some text at the final data points of each of your curves (e.g. x, y point of largest x, for each curve). The arguments x, y can be vectors, and the argument textstring can be a cell array of strings.

Create an array of final data points separately for x and y.

```
xcoords = [x0_final x1_final ...xn_final];

ycoords = [y0_final y1_final ...ym_final];
```

Create a cell array containing your legend strings of the same length as those xcoord and ycoord arrays

```
legend_strings = {'T0 = 0.5', 'T0 = 0.7' ...};
```

Then a call to `text(xcoords,ycoords,legend_strings)` after your plot should do the labeling you want.

Comment: @Reza, if this answer helped you - accept it, if not, explain why, as this is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to comment on each line would be to add labels or text instead of legend.

For instance: 
1)

`labeledge(h,s,t,'T_0=1.5s')`

2)

```
 txt = texlabel('T_0=1.5s')
 text=text(1,1.00E-04,txt)
```

Comment: `labeledge` is irrelevant here, as this is not a graph object, just a simple plot. Also, `texlabel` is not needed, this can be done with simple `text`,